# After changing a views default with hook_views_default_views_alter() how can I make it active programmatically?

Tags: drupal-7, view, defaultview

I have a view. I altered it with hook_views_default_views_alter(). To make my changed become active I need to go to the UI and revert it back to the altered default.

How can I make the new default active programmatically instead?

In other words: How can I alter a views default and make it active programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to revert the view.

You need to include `module_load_include('module', 'views')` and `module_load_include('inc', 'views', 'drush/views.drush')`. And the function to revert all views `views_revert_allviews(views_get_all_views());`.

Check function [hook_views_default_views_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views_alter/7) for more info.